# @parcel/core: Failed to resolve 'index.html' Getting this error

Tags: javascript, parceljs

My package.json file

```
{
"name": "aiky",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "Recipe application",
"default": "index.html",
"scripts": {
  "start": "parcel index.html",
  "build": "parcel build index.html --dist-dir ./dist"
},
"author": "Akash Kesharwani",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
  "@parcel/resolver-glob": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
  "@parcel/transformer-image": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
  "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
  "parcel": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
  "sass": "^1.26.10"
},
"dependencies": {
  "core-js": "^3.6.5",
  "fractional": "^1.0.0",
  "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7"
},
"main": "index.js"
}
```

I can't find the solution over the internet.
Before this, I was getting this error

```
@parcel/core: Failed to resolve 'src/img/test-1.jpg' from './index.html'

@parcel/resolver-default: Cannot load file './src/img/test-1.jpg' in './'.
```

So, I installed @parcel/resolver-glob and also added *.parcelrc* in root with this text

```
{
"extends": "@parcel/config-default",
"resolvers": ["@parcel/resolver-glob"]
}
```

Comment: Can you post a more detailed reproduction (e.g. maybe a github repo that contains a simplified version of your project that will produce the errors above)? In the meantime two guesses about what you might try: (1) you should probably remove `"main": "index.js"` from your `package.json` - that's intended for folks who are developing libraries and (2) maybe change `src/img/test-1.jpg` in you `index.html` to `./src/img/test-1.jpg` - e.g. with the leading dot? (It's hard to know what's actually in that file without the full repro).

Answer (score 5):

It's not very obvious from the [Parcel documentation](https://parceljs.org/features/plugins/#resolvers), but you will need to include the default resolvers by adding the literal string `"..."` to the resolvers array.

> The "..." syntax can be used to extend the default resolvers. This allows you to override the resolution for certain dependencies, but fall back to the default for others. Generally, you'll want to add your custom resolvers before running the default ones.

```
{
  "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
  "resolvers": ["@parcel/resolver-glob", "..."]
                                         ^^^^^
}
```

Comment: well, i thought parcel is no configuration framework, turns out you still need to configure off the get go. for me the workaround so I don't need to worry about this is to run `yarn parcel index.html` directly instead of adding in package.json